# InstantiationException when trying to use file provider in my code?

Tags: android

I am trying to transit from `startActivityForResult` to `registerFor` `ActivityResult` and also use file provider to get access to the content.

```
private void OpenGallery(){
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GalleryPick);// this shows Deprecated
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode==GalleryPick  &&  resultCode==RESULT_OK  &&  data!=null)
    {
        ImageUri = data.getData();
        InputProductImage.setImageURI(ImageUri);
    }
}
```

And app crashes when it hit to click listener.

> `exception:java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.firmvision.waste2wealth.AdminAddNewProductActivity> has no zero argument constructor`

Comment: The error suggests you've created an "AdminAddNewProductActivity" and you've defined a constructor for it yourself. This isn't how you use Android Activties.

Comment: Can you provide the code of AdminAddNewProductActivity?

Comment: We dont see you using FileProvider. But anyhow you should not use it. And there is also no code with AdminAddNewProductActivity and no onClickListener. So what is this about?

Comment: this is the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

You do not need to use the FIleProvider class to get access to the file the user choosed.

Just use the uri obtained.

> > am trying to transit from startActivityForResult to regiserFor ActivityResult

Before you do that just use the old code until yous app does what you want it to do. It should still work as it is only deprecated hence still usable.

Comment: thank you all. i reverted back to the old cold and it work seamlessly. i was having problem getting the image to the current activity but i don't know what had changed now but it is working.